# Function between foot height in cm and shoe size eu

Tags: javascript, function, math, size

On the web is lot of conversion tables between foot height and shoe size. Like here http://www.shoesize.com/men/sizechart/ I would like to ask if there is a math function between those two params. Fuction should looks like:

```
function getShoeSize(height in cm){
  
  ...type magic here...
  
  return shoeSize; //size in EU format
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about international shoe size standards and not programming per se.

Comment: I think it is programming, because there should be a math solution how are those sizes calculated. So it is not only about international shoe size standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that dependence is not very smooth:
[image]

So you can find closest cm size in array with binary search and check if neighbour size is closer (for example, for 26.5 cm binary search can find tabular value 26 as lesser value, but 26.7 is closer, so 42.5 size would fit better). Or use binary search implementation that finds upper value.

Edit: Due to very small array it is simpler to use linear search. Pseudocode:

```
 idx = 0
 while (CmSize[idx] < Foot_len) && (idx < CmSize.Length)
   idx++
 return EUSize[idx]
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is an easy mathematical way of doing it (I am sure it is possible, but it would probably be unreadable for the average developer).

What I suggest you can do, and which is easy to build. Is that you make an array of the shoe sizes (example of all sizes can be found on http://www.shoesizingcharts.com/ and many more sites). And use that array to convert `cm` to `euro size`.

The array could look something like:

```
var shoeSizeMap = [
  { cm: 20.8, euroSize: '35' },
  { cm: 21.3, euroSize: '35' },
  { cm: 21.6, euroSize: '35/36' },
  ... etc
]
```

And use a function to find it like:

```
function findEuroSizeByCm(cm) {
  var result = shoeSizeMap.find(function(shoeSize) {
     return shoeSize.cm == cm;
  });

  return result ? result.euroSize : 'unknown size';
}


findEuroSizeByCm(20.8); // returns 35
```

ps. be aware that I typed in the example the numbers as 'floats' you might want to compare as strings if your data-source is supplying strings as well (just change `cm: 20.8` to `cm: '20.8'`).

Comment: ok thanks, this is a easier solution, which I can use. But I am wondering if is there a math solution, because it looks like that those shoe sizes are determined not in clear way.